# Not able to do facebook login in signed apk?

Tags: java, android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am doing facebook login, when I am testing the app. But as I am creating the signed apk then I am not able to do the login. I don't know what is happening, because same code is working, when I am testing the app normally. Please help me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to add the release key's hash to the facebook as well.

**From FB:**

If you have a release key, you will need to add its hash in the same way. To obtain the release key hash, use the 'keytool' in the same way as in the steps above except for the alias and path.

On OS X, run:

```
keytool -exportcert -alias <RELEASE_KEY_ALIAS> -keystore <RELEASE_KEY_PATH> | openssl sha1 -binary | openssl base64
```

On Windows, use:

```
keytool -exportcert -alias <RELEASE_KEY_ALIAS> -keystore <RELEASE_KEY_PATH> | openssl sha1 -binary | openssl base64
```

Make sure to use the password that you set when you first created the release key.

Save this change.

Comment: Actually I generate the key with the help of code which was given on facebook developer site. So should I need to create Release key like this????

Comment: You need to create hash for your local computer, which you have created and added.. same way you have to do for the sign key (the one which is used to create the signed apk).. read about it here https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/getting-started

Comment: I generated the Release key and use it on facebook, but still I am not able to do login. Pls help me..

Comment: Actually I created a new project and did the same procedure which I did in previous. And it works. Thanks for telling me about "RELEASE KEY", concept...:)